# SR: constant acceleration worldline simultaneity

Tags: special-relativity

A worldline $W$ with constant acceleration $a$ is given parametrically by
$$t=\frac{c}{a} \sinh(\frac{a \tau}{c}), \quad x=\frac{c^2}{a} \cosh(\frac{a \tau}{c}).$$
Let $E=(0,0,0,0)$. I showed that for the velocity $V$,
$$g(V,F-E)=0$$
for any $F$ on the worldline. This implies that "as perceived by an observer with this worldline, the event $E$ is simultaneous with every event in the observer's history". How to make sense of this odd conclusion?

Comment: It's a relativistic line in 2 dimensions - time and space. If by E you mean the restline, then it's a space like line passing through (0,0) and the worldline. An observer moving along the time axis will always receive light (t>0) from the observer moving on the world line, but the observer on the world line never see the reflection from the observer on the time axis.

Answer (score 1):

It's an odd result coming primarily from the fact that hyperbolic cos and sin are eachother's derivatives, with the symmetry between the tilting of the t and x axis towards / away from 45 degrees due to Lorentz boost.

$$\frac{d}{d\tau}\sinh{f(\tau)}=f'(\tau)\cosh{f(\tau)}$$ $$\frac{d}{d\tau}\cosh{f(\tau)}=f'(\tau)\sinh{f(\tau)}$$

$$f(\tau) = \frac ac \tau; f'(\tau)=\frac ac$$

You should end up with the following:

$$\frac{dt}{d\tau} = \frac ac (\frac ca \cosh\frac{a\tau}c) = \cosh\frac{a\tau}c$$
$$\frac{dx}{d\tau} = \frac ac (\frac {c^2}a \sinh\frac{a\tau}c) = c\sinh\frac{a\tau}c$$

Then you can work out the instantaneous velocity in terms of $x$ and $t$, and when you do, something interesting happens...

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{dx}{d\tau}\frac{d\tau}{dt}=\frac{c\sinh\frac{a\tau}c}{\cosh\frac{a\tau}c}$$
$$=\frac{ta}{x\frac{a}{c^2}}=\frac{ta}{xac^{-2}}=c^2 \frac tx$$

If you try to visualize the situation it becomes apparent what is going on:

At the point $(x,t)$ you now know that the velocity is equivalent to $c^2 \frac tx$. Notice that if you plot the slope as a line, this line passes through both $E$ and the point $(x,t)$. The angle of this line with the $x$ axis is identical to the angle made by the $t$ axis and the tangent line at $(x,t)$ which means that indeed, the event at $E$ is considered simultaneous for the entirety of $W$ while there is constant acceleration.

Perhaps it makes more sense if you consider the hyperbolic asymptotes themselves - these are "acceleration horizons" much like an event horizon in that anything beyond them can't be interacted with by something following path $W$. Things right on the asymptotes will appear to have no time passing for them, so any event "caught" in that moment will be simultaneous for more than one instant for something on path $W$. This applies to either asymptote, so as consequence it should apply to where the asymptotes meet: the point $E$.

Comment: Note: I was a little lazy in interpreting whether $x$ in the coordinate sense should include $c^2$ term somewhere; I was working it out in natural units $c = 1$.